# Angular - 2 dependent menus binding

Tags: angularjs

I build a ASP.Net MVC 4 + angular website,
I have an upper menu, while a click on one link will open the left menu links accordingly.
suppose you click the first category (1) upper menu, the left menu will be exposed accordingly 1.1, 1.2, 1.3.

Currently, my upper menu is binded, but when clicking on a link (category), nothing happens on the left menu.
if i put alert, i see the data comes back to the client. it is not a data problem.

any idea guys ? :-)

**my index.html to contain the 2 partials:**

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script src="app/controllers/menuController.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="generalApp">
        <div ng-include="'partials/topMenu.html'"></div>
        <div ng-include="'partials/sideMenu.html'"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

**my upper menu (different html file - working):**

```
    <div ng-controller="menuController">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="category in menuCategories">
                <td>
                    <a href="#" ng-click="loadSideMenu('7')">
                        {{category.CategoryName}}
                    </a>                        
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**my side menu (different html file):**

```
   <div ng-controller="menuController">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="category in sideMenu">
                <td>{{ category.CategoryName }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

**my js controller code:**

```
(function (angular) {
    var generalApp = angular.module('generalApp', [])
        .controller('menuController', function ($scope, $http) {
            $http.post("Home/GetArticleCategories").then(function (response) {
                $scope.menuCategories = response.data;
            });
        $scope.loadSideMenu = function(category) {
            $http.post("Home/GetSideMenu?a="+category).then(function (response) {
                $scope.sideMenu = response.data;
            });
        };
    });

}(angular));
```

**my mvc controller to return the faked links upon the category click :**

```
public JsonResult GetSideMenu(int a)
        {
            var j = Json(new[]{
                    new { CategoryName = "link 1"},
                    new { CategoryName = "link 2"}
                }
            );
            return j;
        }
```

Thanks to any idea !!!

Comment: They are in different menuController scope.They should exist inside the same ng-controller declaration.

Comment: Thanks body ! It looks as the right answer, I just cant understand why putting the both partials inside the same div (in the index page) upon the same controller, is different then giving each one of them the same controller name within their own page like I did...(idea ?)

Comment: look at the answer below!

Answer (score 0):

You must put `upper and left menus` inside the same `ng-contoller`. The way you did every div will have a different **$scope**. When you populate the data in the `upper menu`, the **$scope** from the `upper menu` will hold the list, and the left will not notice that, because they have different **$scopes**.

Think as they are the same kind of object, but different instances!